# How can I center a div and two buttons in relation to an image inside an li?

Tags: html, css

I want to position the text on top of the image, but with 40px margin. I also want to position the two buttons on each side of the li (one on the right side and one on the left side). I've tried with the code below, and various other solution, but with no luck. The closest I've come is what the picture below shows, but the buttons are not in position. I want to have the same layout for every li, so I want this to apply to every li on the page.

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.posts {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}

.post {
    background-color: #606060;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: auto;
    top: auto;
}

.img { 
    background-color: #606060;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-size: contain; 
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.content {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.comment {
    background-color: #006FC4;
    border: 1px solid #00508D;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}

.like {
    background-color: #006FC4;
    border: 1px solid #00508D;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<ul class="posts">

<li class="post">
<div class="content">Test</div>
<button class="comment" onclick="comment('posts/XiqNjxsov3hUXX1zJLk3ta7mQul2/userPosts/PkIm2NOhjOlTZk7J7Dyk')">Comment</button>
<button class="like" onclick="like('posts/XiqNjxsov3hUXX1zJLk3ta7mQul2/userPosts/PkIm2NOhjOlTZk7J7Dyk')">Like</button><img class="img" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mysharify-4ea69.appspot.com/o/posts%2F6.png?alt=media&amp;token=f1881e5e-e9f4-4e90-bf0f-f211a74ccd42" onclick="openImage('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mysharify-4ea69.appspot.com/o/posts%2F6.png?alt=media&amp;token=f1881e5e-e9f4-4e90-bf0f-f211a74ccd42')"></li><br><br>

<li class="post">
<div class="content">dasdasd</div>
<button class="comment" onclick="comment('posts/hg23gh1beGO7cpUvRSkKpqcY9O22/userPosts/TpiuWCRoZQliuhmlj1su')">Comment</button>
<button class="like" onclick="like('posts/hg23gh1beGO7cpUvRSkKpqcY9O22/userPosts/TpiuWCRoZQliuhmlj1su')">Like</button></li><br><br>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for based on your post (would be helpful to have a link to something similar to what you're trying to get), but here's my best guess.

HTML (I removed the second LI, since they'll all look the same anyways and that one didn't have an image)

```
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="posts">
                    <li class="post">
                        <div class="content">Test</div>
                        <button
                            class="comment"
                            onclick="comment('posts/XiqNjxsov3hUXX1zJLk3ta7mQul2/userPosts/PkIm2NOhjOlTZk7J7Dyk')"
                        >
                            Comment
                        </button>
                        <button
                            class="like"
                            onclick="like('posts/XiqNjxsov3hUXX1zJLk3ta7mQul2/userPosts/PkIm2NOhjOlTZk7J7Dyk')"
                        >
                            Like
                        </button>
                        <img
                            alt="foo"
                            class="img"
                            src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mysharify-4ea69.appspot.com/o/posts%2F6.png?alt=media&amp;token=f1881e5e-e9f4-4e90-bf0f-f211a74ccd42"
                            onclick="openImage('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mysharify-4ea69.appspot.com/o/posts%2F6.png?alt=media&amp;token=f1881e5e-e9f4-4e90-bf0f-f211a74ccd42')"
                        />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.posts {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    list-style: none;
}

.post {
    background-color: #606060;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
    background-color: #606060;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.content {
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 40px;
}

.comment {
    background-color: #006fc4;
    border: 1px solid #00508d;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .like {
    background-color: #006fc4;
    border: 1px solid #00508d;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, but I will try this solution tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It works, but will the .post change its height in relation to the height of .content? If .content has a height of say 500px will .post be 500px as well?

Comment: No, it won't. Position: absolute tells every other element to ignore this element for layout purposes, to include height, width, margin, alignment, etc. If you want things to be relative, the simplest way is probably to remove your img tag and set the background-image for each post in your css. Use background-image: url() and remove your background-color for the post.